# What's this problem getting at? (sum and derivative)

Tags: summation

Let $$P(x) = \sum_{m=1}^n b_m (x-a)^m $$
Then $$P^{(k)}(x) = \sum_{m=1} ^n b_m(m)(m-1)\cdots(m-k+1)(x-a)^{m-k}$$
Is above correct? But what about when $m < k$, that seems to ruin the formula?

Then, a side question to above assignment is posed, and it asks somewhat mysteriously: "why do we say that P is unambiguously determined by the first $n$ derivatives $P^k(a)$, $k = 1,\ldots,n$?", and I honestly have no idea what's going on. Do they mean that all other derivatives are zero, so there's no more information to get?

Comment: When $m < k$ one of the terms, $m-i$, in the product will be zero.

Comment: Just note that you are differentiating a polynomial of degree $n$.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it as

> $$P^{(k)}(x)  = k! \sum_{m=0}^{n} {m\choose k}b_m (x-a)^{m-k}.  $$

Comment: You've forgotten the coefficients $b_m$ inside the sum.

Comment: @AlexM.: It's fixed. Thank you.